# What will happen to the Indian plate after it slides under the Eurasian Plate?

Tags: plate-tectonics, mountains, tectonics, mantle, erosion

What will happen if the Indian Plate is done sliding under the Eurasian plate? I hypothesied some possible answers. Tell me the answer and if my hypothesis is not correct.

Most likely to least.

**It will become part of the Eurasian Plate?
It will slide back out of Siberia?
It will get pushed into the mantle?**

I know it is funny to think that the Indian Plate would find its way out of Siberia. I would also want to know what would happen to Mount Everest and the Himalayas.

Comment: It will not slide under the Eurasian plate. The two plates will end sticking up together into one massive plate, with a mountain belt in between (just like the Urals, Appalachians, etc). Mount Everest and the Himalayas formed exactly because of this collision.

Comment: @Gimelist I saw a comment that noted the Indian plate is going under, maybe that's false thanks for the correction though.

Comment: Yea I remember seeing something about that and commenting on that, where there was an animation that showed the collision and someone asked about something that fell into the mantle. I can't find it now?? Maybe it wasn't even on StackExchange??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a continent-continent collision following subduction, no subduction is taking place at the moment. The ocean floor that was attached to it has vanished into the mantle or got wedged into the thickened crust. The collision builds up immense stress, resulting in deformation, faulting, folding, crustal shortening and uplift of the Tibetan plateau.

https://www.files.ethz.ch/structuralgeology/jpb/files/English/Asiaeng.pdf

***Will it become part of the Eurasian Plate?***

That's a question of definition of plate boundaries, fault lines, sutures ...

***Will it slide back out of Siberia?***

Of course not. How could rocks even be preserved in such a process? In the process of shortening the crust is near completely consumed.

***Will it get pushed into the mantle?***

No. Continental crust doesn't subduct. Both sides have approximately equal density and the mantle is much denser, so they just push and shove each other. Maybe parts get pushed to greater depths (~100km) in the dynamic process and exhumed again. Shortening will continue, uplift, faulting, folding and erosion in equilibrium, and when and where uplift stops erosion will take over.

Afterwards there may probably be something like the Appalachians, an older result of a continent-continent collision and a very thick continental crust. Pop-science link depicting the principle: https://www.nps.gov/subjects/geology/plate-tectonics-collisional-mountain-ranges.htm

Comment: +1 This answer is very correct, especially the last part.

Comment: @Earthworm this makes sense, I'm going to accept this answer. I did think about the problem of rock preservation when I was asking about the sliding out of Siberia.

Comment: This answer is logical and makes sense, @Gimelist you have 19,000 Reputation yet you use "+1's" which are clearly stated to avoid.

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome, we need more scientists answering on this forum. Some years ago it was better but people migrated.